# Javascript returning undefined value

Tags: javascript

This is my nuxt js code in one of the methods.

```
this.allCampusWithDeaprtments = campusData.map(
          (item, index) => {
              const schoolData = this.deptInsights.filter((row) => {
                  return row.unit === item.unit;
              }).map(row => {
                  // row.departmentData = row.departmentData || []; 
                  // row.departmentData.push(...this.depts.filter((d) => {
                  //     return d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;
                  // }));
                  // return row;
                  const departmentData = this.depts.filter(
                  d => d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId
                );
                return departmentData
              });

              console.log('department', departmentData);
              // );
              item.id = `toggle-${index}`;
              return {
                  ...item,
                  schoolData,
                  // departmentData,
                  hasOerData: false
              };
          }
      );
```

`departmentData` is not returning any value. What could be the problem? i wand the data which matches the mentioned case in the code

Comment: Your `(row) => {`…`}` function returns nothing, so the filtered list is empty. `const departmentData` is never used. Whatever `departmentData` is outside, it has nothing to do with the `departmentData` inside the `filter`, because it’s out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies here:

```
const departmentData = this.depts.filter((d) => {
            d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;
            return departmentData // 
        })
```

The filter callback requires a boolean to be returned. You are checking a condition `d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;` but not returning it, instead you are returning `departmentData`.
So keeping that in mind, shouldn't your filter code be:

```
this.allCampusWithDeaprtments = campusData.map(
    (item, index) => {
        let departmentData = [];
        const schoolData = this.deptInsights.filter((row) => {
            departmentData.push(...this.depts.filter((d) => {
                return d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;
            }));
            return row.unit === item.unit;

        });

        console.log('department', departmentData);
        // );
        item.id = `toggle-${index}`;
        return {
            ...item,
            schoolData,
            departmentData,
            hasOerData: false
        };
    }
);
```

**EDIT new Structure**

```
this.allCampusWithDeaprtments = campusData.map(
    (item, index) => {
        // let departmentData = [];
        const schoolData = this.deptInsights.filter((row) => {
            return row.unit === item.unit;
        }).map(row => {
            row.departmentData = row.departmentData || []; 
            row.departmentData.push(...this.depts.filter((d) => {
                return d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;
            }));
            return row;
        });

        // console.log('department', departmentData);
        // );
        item.id = `toggle-${index}`;
        return {
            ...item,
            schoolData,
            // departmentData,
            hasOerData: false
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: tried above thing, still its not returning the value

Comment: Edited my code, declared `deparmentData` outside of callback scope.
However, I am not sure what you want as output in `departmentData`. Will it be an array or will it just be matched for only one row?

Comment: Can you explain what you want in output? Do you want to associate `departmentData` of respective schools? Can there exists multiple `depts` for one school data?

Comment: Ii need to get schoolData and departmentData both as arrays,  is there any way?

Comment: Can you explain what you want in output? YES
Do you want to associate departmentData of respective schools? Can there exists multiple depts for one school data? YES

Comment: Separate array or maybe you want department array inside each respective element of school array?

Comment: In campusData.map() i am getting schollData of that campus, then i need departments of that particular school array, and wanna return 2 things, scholldata and departmentData

Comment: I think there might be a better way to solve your problem but I would need more context for that. Can you just try this code first!?

Comment: Hey thanks, tried it, its not giving any error, but its returning only 1 department for each campus not returning all departments of the respective schools

Comment: Edited again. Now try it!

Comment: Its returning blank array

Comment: Each campus contains 2/3 scholos and each school contains 1/ 2 departments, this is how the data structure is

Comment: Sorry, this was my bad. I didn't assign the concat result back to departmentData

Comment: Although, going by your structure explanation, the output data should also be different. Let me edit it.

Comment: Its returning all available departments not the ones belong to a particular school

Comment: Maybe, I got the structure wrong then. The new Edit should have department data integrated right into `schoolData` for each school

Comment: PLease try my edited code.. i want something like this.. but its not working too

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the reasoning of a colleague @sebastian-simon

Your constant is private in the scope. Therefore, it is not defined. Read  [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Try it like this:

```
this.allCampusWithDeaprtments = campusData.map(
let departmentData = null

(item, index) => {
    const schoolData = this.deptInsights.filter((row) => {
        row.unit === item.unit
        departmentData = this.depts.filter((d) => {
            d.sisSchoolId === row.sisSchoolId;
            return departmentData
        })

    }
    );

    console.log('department', departmentData);
    // );
    item.id = `toggle-${index}`;
    return {
        ...item,
        schoolData,
        departmentData,
        hasOerData: false
    };
});
```

Comment: throwing errors using above code, also i need to get schoolData and departmentData

Comment: Then log *this.depts*. I don't see your full project

Comment: schoolData is gone

Comment: I need to get schoolData and departmentData both, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there can be 2 cases:-

1. Your condition is not satisficed as per the data u pass in `campusData` array variable.
2. you are not returning **departmentData**,

```
return const departmentData = this.depts.filter((d) => {...
```

Let me know, if its helpful.